# Windows Server 2016 DC - 8007370b error installing June 2022 cumulative update

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update

For some reason I'm not able to install the June 2022 security update on a Windows Server 2016 domain controller. It fails with error 8007370b every time.

I've already tried resetting WU components and deleting the SoftwareDistribution folder as suggested here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-resources

https://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/360896-windows-7-doesnt-update-error-code-8007370b.html

These did not solve the issue.

Being a domain controller, a system restore is not possible. To be honest at this point I'm really not sure how to continue. I'd rather not have to reinstall the entire OS.

Here are WindowsUpdate.log and CBS.log -

https://mega.nz/file/6AlRBRTT#zB0vdsMIeS_TVBWFQoVwlNffQA39zqo5kBveFX6RHvY

If possible I'd like to try solving this remotely first since it's quite a drive to site but obviously if I have to go there I will.

Thank you!

EDIT: To rule out any network issues I've also tried using a standalone offline MSU from the update catalog and the issue persists.

Comment: This line has some of it.  What is "QublicKeyToken"? Seems to be a jacked up or overwritten file somewhere. I'm guessing this is not a dedicated DC and has other components installed.    `2022-06-16 14:13:58, Error                 CSI    00000009 (F) STATUS_SXS_INVALID_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME #1606516# from Windows::Identity::Rtl::Implementation::CRtlIdentityAuthority::IRtlIdentityAuthority_Parse(flags = 0, string = [l:157]'362e44195cb2767c0dabae379eec18bb, Culture=neutral, Version=10.0.14393.4886, QublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS')`

Comment: It's a dedicated DC. The only 3rd party software installed on it is Firefox and WinRAR.